# Email Send time Optimization

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, classification, data-science

I have a question about optimizing the message (email/push/text etc.) sending time to our subscribers. The desired output will be a time interval of each day for each person.

We have the history of the time when a person opened/clicked our message, their demographic information and some other browsing history. But I am not sure if this could be a machine learning model since each individual behaved so differently and I don't have many good predictors.

Should I just summarize the best reaching time for them in the historical data, or it could be a machine learning model?

Answer (score 3):

In fact many Campaign Management solution do use the technique to identify the best reaching time by simply taking the most frequent email opening time of the user. But this takes its own sweet time to reach a conclusion ie , you send the emails to a user for 10 days and then you have to calculate the the Most frequent opening time of the user .This should work .

That being said , there is  nothing stopping us from using a ML model for this problem as well :)

If you think of your targets(email-opening time of the user) , its a circular in nature , and you could try  *Angular Regression* .

Here are some links to get you started :

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109959/regression-for-angular-circular-data